# Recursive alternative to nested for loop

Tags: python, loops, recursion, scikit-learn, nested

I have 4 different sklearn regressors and I want to use a percentage of each prediction to build my final prediction.

My idea is to loop through each possible version and calculate the RMSE using a percentage of each prediction as my answer i.e

```
reg1.predict(X_test) * 0.2  + reg2.predict(X_test) * 0.3 * reg3.predict(X_test) * 0.3  * reg4.predict(X_test) * 0.2
```

I have the below currently, but I know there is a cleaner way to do it, where I can also easily add more regressors if needed...But I cant get my head round it? I'm pretty sure I need a recursive function? But maybe i'm wrong?

Any ideas/help welcome?

```
step = 0.05
for x in np.arange(0,1,step):
    for y in np.arange(0,1,step):
        for z in np.arange(0,1,step):
            for p in np.arange(0,1,step):
                if round(x,2)+round(y,2)+round(z,2)+round(p,2) == 1:
                    print(f"x = {round(x,2)} y = {round(y,2)} z = {round(z,2)} p = {round(p,2)}")
                    ## RMSE calculation code goes, if best store X,Y,Z,P
```

Comment: Rather than relying on the rounded values summing to exactly 1, check that the sum of the unrounded values falls in a sufficiently small interval, say (0.99, 1.01).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need recursion in and of itself; you are interested in the *product* of the four ranges.

```
from itertools import product

for x, y, z, p in product(np.arange(0,1,step), repeat=4):
    ...
```

Comment: ... `, repeat=...`? Schwweet. Didn't know that was available

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function but maybe try `itertools.product`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a Cartesian product, right? So you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) like this:

```py
import itertools

step = 0.05

configs = itertools.product(
    np.arange(0, 1, step),
    np.arange(0, 1, step),
    np.arange(0, 1, step),
    np.arange(0, 1, step),
)

for x, y, z, p in configs:
    if round(x, 2) + round(y, 2) + round(z, 2) + round(p, 2) == 1:
        print(f"x = {round(x,2)} y = {round(y,2)} z = {round(z,2)} p = {round(p,2)}")
        ## RMSE calculation code goes, if best store X,Y,Z,P
```